# NodeJs Cluster.Fork is not a function

Tags: node.js

Iam using this simple code of lines and i get this error. Iam using Node v10.15

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var s = cluster.fork();
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: cluster.fork is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sdss\Documents\Coding\NodeJs\a.js:17:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check required for cluster fork to start ,cpus length and it's master or not .try the below code

```
    const cluster = require('cluster');
    const http = require('http');
    const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

    if (cluster.isMaster) {
      masterProcess();
    } else {
      childProcess();  
    }

    function masterProcess() {
      console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

      for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        console.log(`Forking process number ${i}...`);
        cluster.fork();
      }

      process.exit();
    }

    function childProcess() {
      console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started and finished`);

      process.exit();
    }
```